# select / redirect / store as $_SESSION['value'] fails

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am trying to do a dropdown menu select / store value in $_SESSION / redirect, but all I am able to get is either the last value in the query or NULL, but never the intended 'select' value.

****************************   *header.php file*  ****************************

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['bolredir'])){

        //store as session variable
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['bolredir'];

        //forward browser
        header("Location: add-job.php");
        exit;

}


$host = "localhost";
$user = "custdb";
$pass = "";
$db = "accounting";


?>
```

****************  index file   *********************

```
<?php require_once("header.php");?>
    <form name="addjob" method="POST" >
    <select name="bolredir">

    <?php
            // selection box submit
            $query = "SELECT * FROM customer";
            $result = $odb->query($query);
            $custkey;
            if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                    foreach($result as $item) {
                            echo '<option value='.$item['id'].'>';
                            echo ($item['cust_name'] .",". $item['cust_addr'] .",". $item['cust_phone'] .",". $item['id']."<br />\n");
                            echo '</option>';
                    }

            }

    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="bolredir" id="bolredir" value="add-job.php"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you call `session_start()`?

Comment: @Fabien Warniez yes, in a called header file. I should of indicated that. Session does work, it just pulls the wrong information   http://i.imgur.com/NO0jky6.png  http://i.imgur.com/86a1lCI.png  <- note in the second image the var_dump() outputs 'peachy'. Of 10 db rows, that's the last. so the session works, just wrong data.  http://bpaste.net/show/183043/

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be called at the very top of the file

Comment: @Magictallguy It is. it is being called from a required file called header.php which is first. kindly refer to the above comment posting.

Comment: full code  http://bpaste.net/show/T7ApM3c16UMobuCvBn8P/

Comment: your `header` redirect will never work, it needs to be called before any output just like `session_start()` - you've put it inside a `select` element, so it will never run.

Comment: @scrowler If I do that, then the page redirects before anything is selected rendering the page as useless.

Comment: Both the select element and the input (type=submit) element have the same name attribute. Please pick a different name for the submit button. That will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should address your problem. You won't win any prizes with this approach though. :-)

```
<form name="addjob" method="POST" >
<select name="bolredir">

<?php
        // selection box submit
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customer";
        $result = $odb->query($query);
        $custkey;
        var_dump($result);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach($result as $item) {
                        echo '<option value='.$item['id'].'>';
                        echo ($item['cust_name'] .",". $item['cust_addr'] .",". $item['cust_phone'] .",". $item['id']."<br />\n");
                        echo '</option>';
                        $custkey = $item['id'];
                        var_dump($custkey);
                }

        var_dump($custkey); //will always have the last value of $item['id']
        if(isset($_POST['bolredir']))
                {
                header("Location: ".$_POST['bolredir']);
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['bolredir'];
                exit;
        }
        }
var_dump($_SESSION['cust_name']);
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="bolredir" id="bolredir" value="add-job.php"/>
</form>
```

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<?php 

    //first start a session
    session_start();

    //capture submitted value
    if(isset($_POST['bolredir'])){

        //store as session variable
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['bolredir'];

        //forward browser 
        header("Location: " . $_POST['bolredir']);
        exit;

    }

?>

<form name="addjob" method="POST" >
<select name="bolredir">

<?php
        // selection box submit
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customer";
        $result = $odb->query($query);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach($result as $item) {
                        echo '<option value='.$item['id'].'>';
                        echo ($item['cust_name'] .",". $item['cust_addr'] .",". $item['cust_phone'] .",". $item['id']."<br />\n");
                        echo '</option>';
                }


        }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="bolredir2" id="bolredir2" value="add-job.php"/>
</form>
```

Comment: that gives me a $_SESSION['id'] value of 'add-job.php'  I must still be missing something  http://i.imgur.com/jDsiGFT.png

Comment: Just noticed the issue - both the select element and the input type submit element have the same 'name' attribute. Please use the example below - it has been fixed.